# How to bind event in the style in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, styles

I have a control where is about 100 hundred TextBoxes, and I need for each of them have binded event to `GotFocus` event (where I select all text).

I cant use `EventSetter` as in `WPF`, so what do you use to bind event in style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to subclass the `TextBox` class and then use that in all your code.

You can then put the `GotFocus` event handler in that subclass, otherwise you'd have to add the `GotFocus` event handler to all your code.

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add your code in here
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML you'd have:

```
<my:MyTextBox ..... />
```